# Javafx combobox not updating dropdown size upon change on realtime?

Tags: javafx, combobox, javafx-8

I am using Javafx v8.0.25-b18.

The problem I occur is that the size of the dynamic combox's dropdown list doesn't change, so if I had initially two items in the dropdown, then the dropdown size will be good for two items, but if I now populate the dynamic combox with three items then I get a small scrollbar inside!?, If I remove an item - I will have a blank space in the combox !?

I want to "reset" the dropdown size each time I put values into it, so it will be the right size each time it gets populated at runtime.

To clarify even more I am adding three images:
1. The first screenshot shows the initial dropdown size of 2

[image: Initial dropdown size of 2]

2. The second screenshot shows the same combox, where now at runtime I am adding 2 values, I EXPECT it to have now a dropdown with the size of 4, but instead the dropdown size stays 2 and only adds an unwanted scrollbar

[image]

3. Last screenshot is when I remove items and only one item remains in the combox, I EXPECT to see a dropdown of 1 item, but instead I unfortunately see a dropdown the size of 2 thus an empty space instead of the second item

[image]

I am adding the simple code to create this scenario, I want to thank @Gikkman that helped getting this far and the code is actually his!

```
public class Test extends Application {

private int index = 0;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

VBox vbox =  new VBox();
vbox.setSpacing(10);
vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

final ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>();
box.setPrefWidth(200);
box.setVisibleRowCount(10);

Button add = new Button("Add");
Button remove = new Button("Remove");

add.setOnAction(    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    box.getItems().add("Item " + index++);
    box.getItems().add("Item " + index++);
  }
});


remove.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    if( index > 0 )
      box.getItems().remove(--index);
  }
});


vbox.getChildren().addAll(add, remove, box);


Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide MVCE.

Comment: Googled it but couldn't understand what does MVCE stand for. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Ok, Now I have a good MVCE

Comment: I couldn't observe the scenario you described. Adding and remving the items shows the dropdown list as fit as expected. The scrollbar is appearing if the item size is more than 10, and that's because of the default value of VisibleRowCount is 10. Even you say you are reusing JavaFX 2, the screenshots you attached are from modena style which is introduced with JavaFX 8. Check the exact version with System.out.println( com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion() ).

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the version is: 8.0.25-b18, I will now go and change the version in the original post.  The behaviour you are describing is what I want, but with the exact code I put in the post, I get the behaviour I described, if it is a version issue, I don't mind upgrading, thanks Uluk

Comment: Hmm I tried with 8.0.40-b26. Can you also try with newer version?

Comment: Ok, I have updated to the latest (as of today): v8.0.60-b27. I think it behaves better, but still it is as if it has radom behaviour, please try clicking add and remove several times, you will see eventually that the size of the dropdown doesn't contain nicely all of the values in the combox

Comment: Here is the new scenario when using latest Java: Click "add" twice, open the dropdown, now click "add" another time - SCROLL (why does it appear?), VS start the app, click "add" three times - NO SCROLL

Comment: I have got 8.0.51-b16 as a latest. And it is also working as expected. The problem can be platform specific, since I am on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
box.hide(); //before you set new visibleRowCount value
box.setVisibleRowCount(rows); // set new visibleRowCount value
box.show(); //after you set new visibleRowCount value
```

It works for me with editable comboBox and I think it will work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I solved it with a quick trick.
Just try to show and immediately hide !

```
add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    box.getItems().add("Item " + index++);
    box.getItems().add("Item " + index++);
    box.show();
    box.hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like to offer my two cents here. You may add the following codes to your combobox which define a custom listview popup that has variable height according to the current number of items. You can tweak the maximum number of items to be displayed in the popup.

```
yourComboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
            ListCell cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    int numItems = getListView().getItems().size();
                    int height = 175;    // set the maximum height of the popup
                    if (numItems <= 5) height = numItems * 35;    // set the height of the popup if number of items is equal to or less than 5
                    getListView().setPrefHeight(height);
                    if (!empty) {
                        setText(item.toString());
                    } else {
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change the number of entries to be displayed. The implementation will handle that automatically.

Say you want to display at most 10 items. Then, you use `comboBox.setVisibleRowCount( 10 );` If there are less than 10 items at any time, Javafx will only show as many rows as there are items.

Actually, changing the number of visible rows at runtime can sometimes cause errors, from my experience, so you are better of with just having a set number.

Hope that helps.

---

I have some problems understanding what the problem is. I made a short example bellow, can you try it and then say what it doesn't do that you want to do.

```
public class Test extends Application{

    private int index = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{

        VBox vbox =  new VBox();    
        vbox.setSpacing(10);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        ComboBox<String> box = new ComboBox<>();
        box.setPrefWidth(200);
        box.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        Button remove = new Button("Remove");

        add.setOnAction(    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                box.getItems().add("Item " + index++);
            }
        });


        remove.setOnAction( new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {       
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if( index > 0 )
                    box.getItems().remove(--index);
            }
        });


        vbox.getChildren().addAll(add, remove, box);


        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried it and it was close but not what I wanted - setVisibleRowCount sets the Maximum number of rows, so if I set it to 1, it won't get higher than 1, but it doesn't set the number of rows, so in my scenario if I set 2 items, then set 3 items, the dropdown will still have a scrolbar...  I think I miss something really basic here :-(

Comment: Edited my answer a bit. Check it out and then return :-)

Comment: I am trying your example - and it works as it should !!

When I click on add it adds an element and it makes the dropdown bigger, when I click on "remove", it removes an element and shortens the dropdown - as it should, but in my app, it doesn't, the dropdown height size stays the same as the first number of values I insert into it!, I am trying to find differences between your app and mine, the most noticeable is that I use an FXML file, while you draw your GUI programatically?

Comment: YES, Found it!!!
 The difference between my code and yours is that you use box.add (or box.remove), while I use box.setItems(). Apparently, when using the setItems() method, the dropdown height doesn't get updated, IMHO this is a bug in JavaFX ?   or maybe it is intentional

Comment: Did you use `box.setItem("")` when you wanted to remove items? Because that is probably the cause of your problem. That doesn't actually remove any items, just sets them to a blank string. Otherwise, I am not sure but I would guess it is intentional, sorta like when you use list.add, list.remove and list.set

Comment: Nope, I used your code and the bug returns when I change the "handle" method of the add button as follows:
        long r = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
          l.add("Item " + i);

        box.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(l));

Can you add this code and look at it please ?

Comment: I was wrong - bug occurs even in your code, the simplest scenario is to put two items instead of one (in the handle method write the adding line twice!: box.getItems().add("Item " + index++); box.getItems().add("Item " + index++);)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two JavaFx list. First one is previous com box list, another one is final combo box list. then you can change dynamically using yourCombo.getItems().setAll(Your List);

Here is my sample code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

      primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
      primaryStage.setHeight(200);
      primaryStage.setWidth(300);

      List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
      list1.add("one");
      list1.add("two");
      list1.add("three");

      List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
      list2.add("one");
      list2.add("two");
      list2.add("three");
      list2.add("four");

      final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();
      combo.getItems().setAll(list1);


      Button button = new Button("Change combo contents");
      button.setOnAction(event -> {
         if ( combo.getItems().size() == 3 ) {
            combo.getItems().setAll(list2);
         } else {
            combo.getItems().setAll(list1);
         }
         combo.show();
      });

      VBox box = new VBox(20, combo, button );
      box.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene( new StackPane(box) ));

      primaryStage.show();

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      launch(args);
   }

}
```