# JavaFX ComboBox doesn't render resized cells

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am trying to write a simple color chooser `ComboBox` in JavaFX 15. I want the dropdown menu to contain a large number of very small cells. Unfortunately, when I set the cell size and increase the number of visible rows, many of them appear empty. It appears that the program is computing the number of cells to render based on how many fit into the `ListView` prior to resizing.

Changing the number of visible rows or the size of the `ListView` results in different numbers of cells being rendered, but the fraction of empty cells remains the same. I've tried to using the `hide()` and `show()` methods to force the `ComboBox` to draw itself again (as suggested here: [Javafx combobox not updating dropdown size upon change on realtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198956/javafx-combobox-not-updating-dropdown-size-upon-change-on-realtime)) and I've tried replacing the backgrounds with `Rectangles` and fiddling with the CSS and `Property` binding, but so far nothing has worked.

Here's my code: Any suggestions?

```
public class ColorComboBox extends ComboBox {

    String[] colorCodes = {"#CD5C5C", "#F08080", "#FA8072", "#E9967A", "#FFA07A", "#DC143C", ...

    ColorComboBox() {
        setCellFactory(lv -> new ColorCell());
        setVisibleRowCount(30);
        getItems().addAll(colorCodes);
     }

    public class ColorCell extends ListCell<String> {
        
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String color, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(color, empty);
            setPrefSize(40, 6);
            if(empty)
                setBackground(null);
            else
                setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.web(color), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));         
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you ignoring the [ColorPicker](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ColorPicker.html) class deliberately for the sake of this exercise?  I’m not sure all users will appreciate a cell that’s 6 pixels high…

Comment: Try either moving the `setPrefSize(40, 6)` to the `ColorCell` constructor, or omit it entirely and use the following in your CSS file: `.combo-box .combo-box-popup .list-view { -fx-fixed-cell-size: 6px ; }`

Comment: @James_D, the second of those suggestions worked for me. Somehow I hadn't been able to find the right attribute previously. Thanks!